# Barcode ID for order/ticket

Tags: eventbrite

Is there a way to get a users barcode id for a ticket/order other than calling event_list_attendees and paging through the attendees trying to find the right user match? This method would be taxing on the eventbrite servers and a lot of unnecessary work/resources from the client side as well.

It seems like this should be included by default with the return json of user_list_tickets. Anyone have any ideas or other ways of doing this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like right now that's not an option.